# Firebase storage only stores one image deletes previous uploaded ones

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to retrieve my data in the listview but noticed all images are the same.  Firebase storage only has one image stored every time.

I have read similar questions and none of them match with my query.
Apologies for uploading images instead of code since I has issue formatting code here
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a method to find file extension as well as saving image in milliseconds solved the problem since images now have different naming method in Firestore

[image]